# Create an array of Class objects by parsing JSON- SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift3, swifty-json

I have a class with some variables and I want to create an array of objects of this class by parsing the JSON output using `SwiftyJSON`(I'm new to SwiftyJSON and so facing some problem while creating one) and display them using a Table

Can someone help me in creating the array of custom class objects.

**My Model class:**

```
    class RankDetailsModel
    {
        var key:String!
        var currentMonthRank: Int!
        var currentRevenue:Double!
        var lastMonthRank:Int!
        var lastMonthRevenue:Double!

        init?(rank: [String: Any]) {

            guard let key = rank["Key"] as? String,
            let currentMonthRank = rank["CurrentMonthRank"] as? Int,
            let currentRevenue = rank["CurrentRevenue"] as? Int,
            let lastMonthRank = rank["LastMonthRank"] as? String,
            let lastMonthRevenue = rank["LastMonthRevenue"] as? String
                else{
                    return nil
            }

            self.key = key;
        self.currentMonthRank = currentMonthRank;
        self.currentRevenue = Double(currentRevenue);
        self.lastMonthRank = Int(lastMonthRank);
        self.lastMonthRevenue = Double(lastMonthRevenue);
        }
    }
```

**JSON response:**

```
{ "AfxRank":
    [{
        "CurrentMonthRank" : 1,
        "Key" : "WSM",
        "CurrentRevenue" : 28834854,
        "LastMonthRevenue": null,
        "LastMonthRank": null
      },
      {
        "CurrentMonthRank" : 2,
        "Key" : "SAM",
        "CurrentRevenue" : 21880000,
        "LastMonthRevenue": null,
        "LastMonthRank": null
      },
      {
        "CurrentMonthRank" : 3,
        "Key" : "CI",
        "CurrentRevenue" : 11380000,
        "LastMonthRevenue": null,
        "LastMonthRank": null
      }]
}
```

**My Code in VC:**

```
var rankArray : [RankDetailsModel] = []
switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):
                    if let data = response.result.value{

                        let jsonD = JSON(data) 
                        let dataNew = jsonD.rawString()?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) 
                        let jsonFinal = JSON(dataNew)
                        print(jsonFinal["AfxRank"]) //successfully printing the json array as shown above
                        rankArray = jsonFinal["AfxRank"].arrayValue as! [RankDetailsModel] //throwing an error 'RankDetailsModel' is not a subtype of JSON

//can I try something like this. (I didnt use SwifyJson and Alamofire in this case)
//if let userDict = json["AfxRank"] as? [String:Any]
//                        {
//                            guard let userObject = //RankDetailsModel(rank:userDict) else {
//                                print("Failed to create user from //dictionary")
//                                return
//                            }   
                    }
                    break

                case .failure(_):
                    print(response.result.error)
                    break

                }
```

Comment: You ultimately need to loop through JSON array, passing data from each parsed object into your model’s initializer. Did you try the approach you mention in the comment?

Comment: @Tony I tried converting it to dictionary as in comments. But it is throwing an error saying `JSON doesnt have any member like [String:Any]`. Will try again and update the correct error message

Answer (score 1):

Your key `AfxRank` contains `Array` not dictionary so you need to type cast it to `[[String:Any]]`, then go through the loop and `append` the object in array of `[RankDetailsModel]`.

```
var rankArray = [RankDetailsModel]()
if let userArray = json["AfxRank"].arrayValue as? [[String:Any]] {
    for dic in userArray {
        if let rankDetailObj = RankDetailsModel(rank: dic) {
            rankArray.append(rankDetailObj)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Nirav. When I used your code it is showing a warning near `if let userArray = json["AfxRank"] as? [[String:Any]] {` - `cast from JSON to unrelated type [[String:Any]] always fail.` When I run the code, its not going inside the if condition and just exiting.

Comment: `[String:Any] is not a subtype of JSON` error near that line :(

Comment: I tried using `if let userArray = json["AfxRank"].arrayObject as? [[String:Any]] {` and its showing no error. But then it is not satisfying the condition `if let rankDetailObj = RankDetailsModel(rank: dic) {` and coming out of if condition without going in.

Comment: @ASN Inside your `init` method before `guard` statement try to print your rank dictionary and check is it printing correctly?

Comment: its printing correctly. it printed something like this . `Rank details in Model class:  ["CurrentMonthRank": 1,"CurrentRevenue": 28834854, "Key": WSM]`

Comment: @ASN May be problem is in this line `let currentRevenue = rank["CurrentRevenue"] as? Double` use `as? Int` then covert you int to Double.

Comment: Hi Nirav. I think its because of what you said above. But I have a situation where for `Int` value they are passing `null` instead of `0`. so While converting `int` to `double` its throwing an error. 

this is what I'm doing. 
`let currentRevenue = rank["CurrentRevenue"] as? Int` and then `self.currentRevenue = Double(currentRevenue)`. if there is any value its perfectly converting but if it is `null` then I'm facing a problem

Comment: Instead of converting to string using `as? String` for `LastMonthRevenue` and `LastMonthRank` use `as? Int` and check it is still crashing.

Comment: its crashing if I change it to `Int` and then convert it to `Double(LastMonthRank)`

Comment: @ASN The thing i doesn't understand is if it is nil than it should go with return.

Comment: Its going to `return` in the `init` and then coming out of the condition`if let rankDetailObj = RankDetailsModel(rank: dic) {` and iterating to next item